# Where should "back to top" on long FAQ page link to?

Tags: labels, hyperlinks, faq

My FAQ page consists of a table of contents (with links jumping to each FAQ entry) and all FAQ entries. The entries are grouped in sections.

> ### FAQ
>
> #### ToC (`#toc`)
>
> Section 1 (`#toc-section-1`)
>
> - QA 1 (`#toc-qa-1`)
> - QA 2 (`#toc-qa-2`)
>
> Section 2 (`#toc-section-2`)
>
> - QA 3 (`#toc-qa-3`)
> - QA 4 (`#toc-qa-4`)
>
> ---
>
> #### Section 1
>
> QA 1
>
> QA 2
>
> #### Section 2
>
> QA 3
>
> QA 4

The page can get long: many sections, many FAQ entries. So after each FAQ entry, I’m providing a "back to top" hyperlink. **Where should "back to top" link to?**

When reading QA 3, should it link to `#toc`, `#toc-section-2`, or `#toc-qa-3`?

And if it should link to some other place than the top/ToC, should the label be something else than "back to top"?

Answer (score 0):

> So after each FAQ entry, I’m providing a "back to top" hyperlink.

Why not just provide a single button which stays at the bottom right corner of the page? And show it once the user has scrolled down and hide it when the user is at the top section of the page?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/3164/

[image]

Comment: I guess I should have made it explicit in my question, but the idea is: **Wouldn’t it be useful to go back to the ToC at the position of the Q/A (or of its section) they just read?** With your suggestion, it would still be possible to change the anchor target depending on which Q/A is in view, so the question would be the same: where should this link ideally link to? Top of the table of contents is the typical solution, but is it the best (for a long ToC)? Users would then have to scroll down the ToC to find (again) the Q/A they just read.

Comment: @unor I think in that case the back to the top should link to the current section's top. The text can be replaced with back to Section 1/ Section 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the "same thing", a common technique in Kindle e-books is to have chapter headings act as links back to the table of contents. In some cases, this might just be to the beginning of the ToC (like a "dumb" back-to-top link); in more carefully thought-out cases, it takes you to the corresponding entry in the ToC (which is what you sound like you want to do).

So: In the ToC, each entry (chapter, section, Q&A etc.) will take you to the appropriate place on the page. The headings within the page itself could take you to the appropriate location within the ToC (at minimum ensuring that entry is visible; ideally, if possible, setting focus on the entry).

You could additionally have a button either bottom-right, or in a fixed header (if present) that takes you to the very top of the ToC.